# Slurm: How could I return all the completed jobs submitted by a some user?

Tags: slurm

Following command `squeue -U < user_name >` returns all the jobs that are only running, pending or queued, which are submitted by the user.

[Q] How could I return all the completed jobs submitted by the user? also it is possible to obtain submitted jobs' process_id instead of the job_id?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
sacct --start=YYYY-MM-DD -u < user_name>
```

to get all completed or failed jobs from user `user_name` since date `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Thank you sir, I have additional following question(http://stackoverflow.com/q/43684707/2402577) related you your guide. @damienfrancois

Comment: How do I use this command if I don't know the start date?

Comment: Just use a date further enough back in the past. `--start` is the start of the "search period" for `sacct` to consider, not the start time of the job.