# SLURM: When we reboot the node, does jobID assignments start from 0?

Tags: slurm

For example:

`sacct --start=1990-01-01 -A user` returns job table with latest jobID as 136, but when I submit a new job as `sbatch -A user -N1 run.sh` submitted bash job returns 100 which is smaller than 136. And seems like sacct -L -A user returns a list which ends with 100.

So it seems like submitted batch jobs overwrites to previous jobs' informations, which I don't want.

**[Q]** When we reboot the node, does jobID assignments start from 0? If yes, what should I do it to continue from latest jobID assignment before the reboot?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main reasons why job ID's might be recycled:

- the maximum job ID was reached (see `MaxJobId` in slurm.conf)
- the Slurm controller was restarted with `FirstJobId` set to a new value

Other than that, Slurm will always increase the job ID's.

Note that the job information in the database is not overwrite; they have a unique ID which is different from the job ID.  `sacct` has a `-D, --duplicates` option to view all jobs in the database. By default, it only shows the most recent one among all those which have the same job ID.

Comment: As a solution, I could give very large value to `MaxJobId` like 1 million? and how could I disable Slurm controller to restart with `FirstJobId` set to a new value? Please note that `MaxJobId` and `FirstJobId`  was commented out on my conf file. @damienfrancois